# Ubuntu, printing page to windows printer works except on firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, samba

Just installed Ubuntu 11.04, setup a zebra label printer, and a HP LaserJet 4050t.

Both printers are set up on a networked windows computer and I am connecting to them using samba.

Both printers work fine printing a test page, and printing from a text editor, the label printer works fine from Firefox, but the hp printer doesn't, Ubuntu says the page was sent to the printer and was completed.

The hp printer has a display, and if its in sleep mode, and you try to print from Firefox, it wakes up, but still does nothing.

I have the newest Firefox (7)

Iam fairly new to the GUI version of linux, I have a Ubuntu server running our companies website, but never had to mess with printers on it so this is all new to me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change the resolution of the printer can work.. I have just do it (from 600x660 default to 300x300) and it has worked for me

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  Are you sure you're talking about the same issue?  It isn't obvious why lowering the resolution would affect the printer not producing output.  The printer is capable of 1200x1200 resolution.